# Can a Mapping Data Flow use a parameterized Parquet dataset?

Tags: parquet, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

thanks for coming in.

I am trying to develop a Mapping Data Flow in an Azure Synapse workspace (so I believe that this can also apply to ADFv2) that takes a Delta input and transforms it straight into a Parquet -formatted output, **with the relevant detail of using a Parquet dataset pointing to ADLSGen2 with parameterized file system and folder**, in opposition to a hard-coded file-system and folder, because this would take creating too many datasets as there are too many folders of interest in the Data Lake.

[image]

The Mapping Data Flow:
[image]

As I try to use it as a Source in my Mapping Data Flows, the debug configuration (as well as the parent pipeline configuration) will duly ask for my input on those parameters, which I am happy to enter.

Then, as soon I try to debug or run the pipeline I get this error in less than 1 second:

```json
{
"Message": "ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=The expression 'body('DataFlowDebugExpressionResolver')?.50_DeltaToParquet_xxxxxxxxx?.ParquetCurrent.directory' is not valid: the string character '_' at position '43' is not expected."
}
```

`RunId: xxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx`

This error message is not very specific to know where I should look.

I tried replacing the parameterized Parquet dataset with a hard-coded one, and it works perfectly both in debug and pipeline -run modes. However, this does not gets me what I need which is the ability to reuse my Parquet dataset instead of having to create a specific dataset for each Data Lake folder.

There are also no spaces in the Data Lake file system. Please refer to these parameters that look a lot like my production environment:

- File System: `prodfs001`
- Directory: `synapse/workspace01/parquet/dim_mydim`

Thanks in advance to all of you, folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory name synapse/workspace01/parquet/dim_mydim has an _ in dim_mydim, can you try replacing the underscore, or maybe you can use dimmydim to test whether it works.